# How to put statsmodels OLS parameter in a dictionary?

Tags: python, statsmodels

I am fitting my data with using linear regression. I want to put the parameter results `y= ax+b` in a dictionary.  I need to extract `(a,b)`:

```
params_dict = defaultdict(list)
results = sm.OLS(Y, sm.add_constant(X)).fit()
print('params('+str(key)+','+str(train_key)+') = '+str(results.params))
print('confidence_Interval('+str(key)+','+str(train_key)+') = '+str(results.conf_int(alpha=0.05, cols=None)))
params_dict['Pair_Nodes'].append((key,train_key))
params_dict['param_A'].append(float(results.params[0]))
params_dict['param_B'].append(float(results.params[1]))
```

However I got this error:

```
    params_dict['param_B'].append(float(results.params[1]))
IndexError: index 1 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 1
```

I want to have the results look like this:

```
params_dict={('Node1,Node2','A','B'),('Node1,Node2','A','B'),..}
```

This is an parameter where I have the problem output:

```
params(02141592cc00000001,02141592cc00000001) = [6.46004214e-10]
```

The expected dictionary:

```
defaultdict(<class 'list'>, {'param_A': [2.5039286220812003e-18], 'Pair': [('02141592cc00000001', '02141592cc00000001')], 'param_B': [3.8760252600949106e-09]})
```

  -

Comment: @Parfait I edit my question.

Comment: @Parfait sorry I put the wanted print

Comment: @Parfait the problem is that I have one parameter output the time that I expect two. I added `sm.add_constant(X)` but it does not resolve the problem.

Comment: Please post data of `Y` and `X`. Are they numpy arrays or pandas columns? (and delete above old comments, hover over to see `x`).